# Error in making df from generator

Tags: python, pandas, yield

I have following code :

```
def read_files(): #generator
    for file_name in glob.glob(path_u_test): 
        yield pd.read_csv(file_name, names=...)

x=read_files()
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

So the problem is that I have not correct data frame on out.Where is mistake?

This outputs

```
Empty DataFrame Columns: [time, probe_name, ji...
1   time probe_name jitter_d...
2   Empty DataFrame Columns: [time, probe_name, ji...
3   Empty DataFrame Columns: [time, probe_name, ji...
4   time probe_name jitter_di...
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Otherwise, it is impossible to tell what your code is supposed to do; your code as posted is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved
Just need this `pd.concat(read_files())` instead of this

```
x=read_files()
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```